# Java boolean methods and word algorithms

Tags: java, methods, boolean, substring

I'm trying to understand the below question. I kind of know what the method is doing, and it returns True. Also, I don't understand the question. I believe the answer is 2, but I don't know why. Below is the method and question.

In the ABBAB language the alphabet has only two letters. A string of letters (including and one-letter strings) is a valid word, if and only if the isValid method returns true for that string. isValid is defined as follows:

```
 public boolean isValid(String word)
{
 int n = word.length();

 return n < 1 ||
      (isValid(word.substring(0, n-1) && 
           word.charAt(n-1) == 'B') ||
      (isValid(word.substring(0, n-2) &&
           "BA".equals(word.substring(n-2)));
}
```

How many valid words of length 7 are there in the ABBABA language?

2
 3
 15
 23
 34

Comment: Are you in the middle of an exam?

Comment: No I was just studying it from an online multiple choice practice test. @JimGarrison

Comment: break it down: `(isValid(word.substring(0, n-1) &&  word.charAt(n-1) == 'B')` says a string is valid if the last letter has to be 'B', and the rest of string is also valid (by applying the recursive definition of valid to the rest of the string. This will tell you valid strings are of the form `******B`

Comment: Okay Cool I think I understand. Now what about the question they ask at the end? @Ben

Comment: See the edit and you tell me. I also didn't complete the analysis for you either

Comment: A word is valid if it ends in `B` or `BA` and the rest of the word is valid by applying the same definition recursively.  It should be easy to enumerate all valid words of length 7.  Hint: `BBBBBBB` is a valid word, as is `BABABAB`.  Start from the right and work backwards.

Comment: Because of the recursive nature I think it's also just as valid to build up a list of valid strings of length 1, length 2, and so on.

Comment: Awesome I definitely understand the conditions they are checking. I still don't really understand the question though. Being that the test is done on paper, how would I know how many valid words there are with length 7? @JimGarrison

Comment: You would apply the rules right-to-left to enumerate all possible valid length-7 words.  The two starting points are `......B` and `.....BA`. So taking the first one, the next two choices are `.....BB` and `....BAB`.  This generates a tree of suffixes. You repeat this recursively on each branch and sub-branch until the word length is 7.  If this doesn't get you to the solution, then I highly recommend you talk to your teacher.